# Want to change File create/modify date to match year in filename via Automator

Tags: macos, bash, applescript, automator

I have movie files like: "The American 2010.avi".  I would like to be able to create an automator Service so I can right-click on one or more files, choose the service.  The Automator script would seek out the 4 number year "2010" from the filename and change the Date created and date modified to match.

Answer (score 0):

You can touch file based on `4-digits` in filename:

```
ytouch() {
    local year=`echo "$1" | egrep -o '[0-9]{4}'`
    if [ -n "$year" ];then
        touch -d "$year-1-1" "$1"
    fi
}
```

---

#### Example:

```
$ ytouch "The American 2010.avi"

$ ls -l "The American 2010.avi"
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 2010-01-01 00:00 The American 2010.avi
```

Comment: hmm, on my Mac, the `touch` utility does not have a `-d` option. Instead, it supports file time assignment in the format `touch -t [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]]`

Comment: @fanaugen Sorry, I didn't test in Mac. You can change the script to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a command line tool to help you change the creation and modification dates. You can get it [here](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/ChangeFileDates/ChangeFileDates.html). I found several issues in the normally available tools such as using finder applescript commands and a command line tool apple supplies with the developer tools. Thus the reason for my tool. Anyway, you can use it if you like and there's an example applescript at the bottom of the web page to guide you. Of course this doesn't do everything you need but it's a good starting point. Good luck.